# Error Parsing JSON,but code seems Ok

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, exception

First of all,thanks for reading my question.

i have the following Json as a result of a web request.

```
{"GetCommunicationsResult":"
   {\"Rows\":
      [{\"Data\":\"2011-12-16T00:00:00\",\"Teacher\":\"Surname Name\",
       \"Communication\":\"bla bla bla and bla bla bla\"},

       {\"Data\":\"2011-10-18T00:00:00\",\"Teacher\":\"Surname Name\",
        \"Communication\":\"bla bla bla and bla bla bla\"}]
   }"
 }
```

I need to decode it in order to use my program.

1. Firstly, i grab the JSON as a string resource

   ```
   JSONObject jsonData = readUrl("http://myWebSite/folder/site.svc/Communications/000884");
   ```

   (readurl is a method that returns the json as a string)
2. Then i create a JSONObject by the use of this string

   ```
   JSONObject BaseObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
   ```

   (strangely,the JSONObject constructor doesn't provide any Inputstream or Reader 
   parameter,but only strings or similar)
3. Finally,i try to reduce my JSON

   ```
   JSONObject DerivatedObject=BaseObject.getJSONObject("GetCommunicationsResult");
   ```

But i encounter a strange exception:

```
Value {"Rows":[{"Data":"2011-12-16T00:00:00","Teacher":"Surname Name","Communication":"bla bla bla and bla bla bla"},{"Data":"2011-10-18T00:00:00","Teacher":"Surname Name","Communication":"bla bla bla and bla bla bla"}]} 
at GetCommunicationsResult of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?
I cannot find out why my code actually finds the JSON but it can't decode it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an errant quote.  See the last open quote on this line:

```
{"GetCommunicationsResult":"
```

That's causing the value to be a string and not a JSONObject.  You can tell it's a string because all other "'s are escaped in the JSON:

```
{\"Rows\":
```

That should be;

```
{"Rows":
```

So something is wrong on the server that's causing that problem.  Maybe you are putting something like this:

```
jsonObject.put("GetCommunicationsResult", someJsonObject.toString() );
```